# plotly , plotting candlesticks <daily , anyone attempted

Tags: python, plotly, algorithmic-trading

Anyone attempted to plot hourly candles on python using plotly? I am trying but you basically get all the candlestick hours plotted on top of eachother based on the date . Is there a way to plot for hours where it inputs date and time to stop any overlapping? code I've started below

```
fivedaydata.tail()

import plotly.graph_objects as go

#create 1 week graph 5 days = 120hrs 

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=fivedaydata.Time,
                open=fivedaydata['Open'],
                high=fivedaydata['High'],
                low=fivedaydata['Low'],
                close=fivedaydata['Close'])])

fig.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8L04m.png)

Answer (score 1):

- have picked up some sample OHLC data and then re-simulated it as hourly.  Within this simulation, I've taken idea that only trading hours are wanted.
- have plotted this with exactly your code,  it works.  Have gaps for hours where there is no trading and days (weekends) where there is no trading
- have plotted again, but using dataframe index as *xaxis*.  Updated **axis** ticks with values from **Time** column
- in neither case are candles being plotted on top of each other.  I can only assume that your **Time** column is a string and repeating across trading days

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# get some data
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv")

# remap to 5 days of hourly data... hence only 8 hrs a day
fivedaydata = (
    df.head(8 * 5)
    .assign(Time=np.array([pd.date_range(d + pd.Timedelta(hours=9), freq="H", periods=8)
                           for d in pd.bdate_range(df.loc[0, "Date"], periods=5, freq="B")
                          ]).flatten()
    )
    .rename(columns={c: c.split(".")[1] for c in df.columns if "AAPL" in c})
)

go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Candlestick(
            x=fivedaydata.Time,
            open=fivedaydata["Open"],
            high=fivedaydata["High"],
            low=fivedaydata["Low"],
            close=fivedaydata["Close"],
        )
    ]
).show()

go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Candlestick(
            x=fivedaydata.index,
            open=fivedaydata["Open"],
            high=fivedaydata["High"],
            low=fivedaydata["Low"],
            close=fivedaydata["Close"],
        )
    ]).update_layout(xaxis = {"tickmode":'array',"tickvals" : fivedaydata.index,
                              "ticktext" : fivedaydata["Time"].dt.strftime("%H%p %d %b")})
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks , I merged by date and time into datetime and passed this as x and it worked.

Comment: ok - so your *Time* column is time data type but repeating.  Hence functional behaviour is as expected...  you could combine date & time as **datetime64** and use that,  just needs to identify candle on x-axis.